# Generate cron expression for two years

Tags: cron

I need to generate cron expression for every 10 min in the date range October 2017 to Feburary 2018.

I tried the following expression:

```
 0 10 0 ? 10-2 * 2017-2018,
```

But its not a valid expression. I get this error message:

> ((Month) - Unsupported value '10-2' for range. ),

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this:

```
*/10 * * 2-10 * 2017,2018 command here
```

from [nncron.ru](http://www.nncron.ru/help/EN/working/cron-format.htm) page:

```
* * * * * *
| | | | | | 
| | | | | +-- Year              (range: 1900-3000)
| | | | +---- Day of the Week   (range: 1-7, 1 standing for Monday)
| | | +------ Month of the Year (range: 1-12)
| | +-------- Day of the Month  (range: 1-31)
| +---------- Hour              (range: 0-23)
+------------ Minute            (range: 0-59)
```

if you want to test other format, use this page http://cronsandbox.com/

Comment: @infi If this answer solved your issue, please award it the green tick.  This is how you reward volunteers who provide the best working answer.  If this doesn't solve your issue, please leave marcelo a comment and update your question to clarify what is still wrong.